# Smash product of $I_+$ with a space $X$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $K_+$ denote the union of $K$ with a disjoint base point.What is in words $X\wedge I_+$ where $I=[0,1]$?

Comment: In words, it is the cylinder on $X$ with the line through the basepoint of $X$ crushed to a point.

Comment: And that line lies in $X$ or in the cylinder?

Comment: In the cylinder, running tangent to $I$ above the basepoint of $X$.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by tangent to $I$? Do we have some manifold-like structure on the cylinder to speak about tangentiality?

Comment: I was referring to the trivial bundle structure of the cylinder over $X$. $I$ is a smooth manifold with boundary, but I wasn't trying to make any specific reference to it. Rather I was trying to describe a straight line in the cylinder in words rather than using mathematical symbols.

Comment: (I mean, is it note more useful just to write $X\wedge I_+=(X\times I\sqcup X\times\{+\})/(X\times\{+\}\sqcup \{\ast\}\times I)=X\times I/\{\ast\}\times I$, than to try and get verbose?)

Comment: How can I see that the result of the quotient $/$ is independent of the order of $\sqcup$ terms? (You have switched these two in you middle term in your string of equalities.)

Comment: The first equality is the definition of the smash product. The quotient by $X\times\{+\}\sqcup \{\ast\}\times I$ is performed in one operation. The final equality comes from the fact that $X\times I\sqcup X\times \{+\}$ is topologised as the indicated disjoint union, and the quotienting subset has the previously indicated form.